# Does neutrino oscillation imply that the lightest neutrino has mass?

Tags: mass, neutrinos

If my understanding is correct, neutrino oscillation only implies that the neutrino families have different masses. People usually infer from this that all the masses are non-zero, but we can only truly infer that at most one of the neutrino masses is zero. So, how can we really know that the lightest neutrino has some mass?

Comment: This video from FermiLab might help - [How do neutrino oscillations work? | Even Bananas 10](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eBT1-dV1BTM)